# uwsgi not starting up

Tags: python, python-2.7, uwsgi, rhel7

I keep getting this error in by terminal after `pip install uwsgi` and running `uwsgi`

I've tried various things thinking it is a gcc path error so added the location to `libc.so.6` but it didn't help.

```
!!! uWSGI process 10506 got Segmentation Fault !!!
*** backtrace of 10506 ***
uwsgi(uwsgi_backtrace+0x2c) [0x46429c]
uwsgi(uwsgi_segfault+0x21) [0x464641]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x35670) [0x7fc0fe450670]
uwsgi(uwsgi_setup+0x24b) [0x466a5b]
uwsgi(main+0x9) [0x41ac29]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7fc0fe43cb15]
uwsgi() [0x41ac59]
*** end of backtrace ***
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer...It's because `pip install uwsgi` needs to be on version `2.0.14` instead of `2.0.15`...There is definitely a bug in the newer version!